# Computing LJ force from LJ potential, or not?

Tags: c++, molecular-dynamics

Lennard-Jones force can be computed in two different ways:

**Version #1:**

Here, the force computation is a self-contained routine.

```
Vec3 lj_force(const Vec3& r)
{
    double r_mag = std::sqrt(r.x * r.x + r.y * r.y + r.z * r.z);
    double s_over_r = sigma / r_mag;
    double s_over_r6 = s_over_r * s_over_r * s_over_r * s_over_r * s_over_r * s_over_r;
    double s_over_r12 = s_over_r6 * s_over_r6;
    double factor = 24.0 * epsilon * (2.0 * s_over_r12 - s_over_r6) / (r_mag * r_mag * r_mag);

    Vec3 force;
    force.x = factor * r.x;
    force.y = factor * r.y;
    force.z = factor * r.z;
    return force;
}
```

**Version #2:**

Here, the force is computed by reusing the potential routine.

```
// Lennard-Jones potential function
double lj_potential(const Vec3& r)
{
    double r_mag = std::sqrt(r.x * r.x + r.y * r.y + r.z * r.z);
    double s_over_r = sigma / r_mag;
    double s_over_r6 = pow(s_over_r, 6);
    return 4.0 * epsilon * (s_over_r6 * s_over_r6 - s_over_r6);
}

// Derivative of the Lennard-Jones potential
Vec3 lj_force(const Vec3& r)
{
    // Define a small distance for the derivative approximation
    double dr = 1e-6;
    Vec3 force;
    std::vector<Vec3> r_plus_dr = { r, r, r };
    r_plus_dr[0].x += dr;
    r_plus_dr[1].y += dr;
    r_plus_dr[2].z += dr;
    // The force is the negative derivative of the potential energy
    force.x = -(lj_potential(r_plus_dr[0]) - lj_potential(r)) / dr;
    force.y = -(lj_potential(r_plus_dr[1]) - lj_potential(r)) / dr;
    force.z = -(lj_potential(r_plus_dr[2]) - lj_potential(r)) / dr;
    return force;
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Which one is computationally more accutate and why?
2. Which ine is preferable in Molecular Dynamics simulation and why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77096751/computing-lj-force-from-lj-potential-or-not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which one is computationally more accutate [sic] and why?

The first one is more accurate. It uses the exact derivative of the LJ potential.

By contrast, the second one not only uses a numerical approximation for the derivative, but uses a particular fixed value for the finite difference denominator `dr`, which may not always be suitable, depending on the value of `r` and the quirks of floating-point arithmetic.

> Which ine [sic] is preferable in Molecular Dynamics simulation and why?

Also the first one, because it is at least as performant as the second version and doesn't require an approximation.

Comment: I agree completely. He may use the second one to double-check the analytical implementation!